# How work with observables?

Tags: angular

I have been working with angularjs for some time and I'm starting to work with Angular (angular.io) But I'm having trouble understanding Observables (this is my first app).

I have a HTTP response that need be transformed by D3.js to a D3.hierarchy, then I return a empty Observable with `of`  in `getResumo$()` (Rentabilidade.service.ts)

This empty Observable will be subscribed in the component (resumo.component.ts).

In the service, because I need transform data, I subscribed the Observable to manipulate data and update this empty observable.

But the `console.log(d)` in my component never update. Only print `undefined` in my console.

What am I doing wrong ?

P.S: If I insert a `console.log(this.hierarchy$)` in my service, the data was updated, but not propagated to component.

**Rentabilidade.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable, Observer, of, from} from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as d3 from "d3";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RentabilidadeService {
    private f_rntb_agg_rsmo = 'http://localhost/api/index.php/bco_dav_dm/f_rntb_agg_rsmo';
    private hierarchy$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
  }

  getResumo$(): Observable<any> {

    this.http.get(this.f_rntb_agg_rsmo)
    .pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError('getResumo',[]))
    )
    .subscribe(d => {

    let nest = d3.nest()
      .key(k => 'root')
      .key(k => k.servico)
      .key(k => k.produto_comercial)
      .key(k => k.canal)
      .key(k => k.ddd)
      .key(k => k.nome_rede)
      .entries(d);

    let hierarchy =  d3.hierarchy(nest[0], h => h.values)
    
    hierarchy.eachAfter(x=> {x.contribuicao = x.sum(y=>y.contribuicao_mes_atul).value;
                  x.contribuicao_mom = x.sum(y=>y.contribuicao_mes_atul - y.contribuicao_mes_antr).value;
                  x.contribuicao_yoy = x.sum(y=>y.contribuicao_mes_atul - y.contribuicao_ano_antr).value;
    });

    this.hierarchy$ = hierarchy;
  }
  )
  return Observable.create(observer => observer.next(this.hierarchy$));

  }
  
  private handleError(operation = 'nao informado', result?: any) {
    return (error: any): Observable<any> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result);
    }
  }
}
```

***resumo.component.ts***

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RentabilidadeService } from '../rentabilidade.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'rentabilidade-resumo',
  templateUrl: './resumo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./resumo.component.css']
})
export class ResumoComponent implements OnInit {
  
  resumo = [];

  constructor(private rentabilidadeService: RentabilidadeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rentabilidadeService.getResumo$()
    .subscribe(d => {this.resumo = d; console.log(d)});
  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `getResumo$` method `http.get()` is an asynchronous call, The return call of your function won't wait till it gets a response from the server.

If you want to manipulate the data from the http request you can try this method.

Return the http request method and then write your data nesting functions on the component. If you opt this method, Then you may have to write same methods in multiple places on your app(unless you use a service) if you have more than one components that rely on this type data manipulation.
example:

```
    getResumo$(): Observable<any> {
       retun this.http.get(this.f_rntb_agg_rsmo);
    }
```

then subscribe the response on your `component.ts` file.

Or you can wrap entire `getResumo$()` inside an `Observable.create`
example:

```
getResumo$(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(observer => {
    this.http.get(this.f_rntb_agg_rsmo)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('getResumo',[])))
        .subscribe(d => {
      let nest = d3.nest()
      .key(k => 'root')
      .key(k => k.servico)
      .key(k => k.produto_comercial)
      .key(k => k.canal)
      .key(k => k.ddd)
      .key(k => k.nome_rede)
      .entries(d);

      let hierarchy =  d3.hierarchy(nest[0], h => h.values)

      hierarchy.eachAfter(x=> {x.contribuicao = 
        x.sum(y=>y.contribuicao_mes_atul).value;
        x.contribuicao_mom = x.sum(y=>y.contribuicao_mes_atul - 
        y.contribuicao_mes_antr).value;
        x.contribuicao_yoy = x.sum(y=>y.contribuicao_mes_atul - 
        y.contribuicao_ano_antr).value;
      });
      this.hierarchy$ = hierarchy;
      observer.next(this.hierarchy$));
    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Did not work. Get Error because the return is inside of subscribe.  What I want is emit that the value in Obsevable was changed in my service to be detected in my subscribe in my component. How I make this ?